# Trying to create this blackjack type game. Can't get printf to work

Tags: c

So whenever I try running this code it will go through the first printf but it displays the second one without letting me input a value. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int suit1;
    int suit2;
    char H, S, C, D;
    float value1;
    float value2;
    printf("Please enter the card's suit");
    scanf("%d", &suit1);
    printf("Please enter the card's value");
    scanf("%f", &value1);
    printf("%d %f", suit1, value1);
}
```

Comment: Add something like `printf("%d %f", suit1, value1);` after the second scanf.  Also, you probably meant to say `scanf("%f", &value1);`

Comment: @Nirk Thank you however, it still skips the second scanf without letting me input any data.

Comment: Are you possibly entering a letter?  the way your scan is set up, you should be reading an integer for the suit and a float for the value (so inputting `H`, for example, would result in 0 for both values)

Comment: Running the above code allowed me to input the values. Make sure you are not running this on an online compiler like ideone or such. Those are not interactive and you need to provide input before-hand

Comment: Please tell us _exactly_ what characters you are typing (values, space, carriage returns, ...) and what you see on the console when you say "without letting me input any data". It is not clear what your problem is...

Comment: Ok. so I use Xcode to run it. I changed all of the cards ("Hearts, Spades etc") to letters like you said @Floris. When I run the program it then asks to enter the card's suit. I then put H for hearts. This then goes to the next printf where it asks me to enter the cards value however I cannot enter it because it ends the program.

Comment: You need to tell your code to expect a letter - if you leave the `scanf("%d", &suit1);` unchanged, no number is found and this will mess things up. Let me update my answer a bit...

Answer (score 1):

Consider using characters ("CDHS") for the suits, and integers for the cards (rather than floating point numbers - although they can represent small integers without loss of precision). It is usually a good idea to make the internal representation of variables "close to the real world" when you can...

With a small modification, your program works fine for me (**UPDATED** in light of your recent comments above):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int suit1;
    int suit2;
    char suitInput;
    char Hearts, Spades, Clubs, Diamonds;
    int value1;
    int value2;
    printf("Please enter the card's suit (C, D, H or S): ");
    scanf("%c", &suitInput);

    printf("\nPlease enter the card's value: (1 = Ace, up to 13 = King): ");
    scanf("%d", &value1);
    printf("\nYou entered %c, %d\n", suitInput, value1);
}
```

The output I get:

```
Please enter the card's suit (C, D, H or S): D

Please enter the card's value: (1 = Ace, up to 13 = King): 5

You entered D, 5
```

Comment: I have changed this however it still does the same thing.

Comment: Are you using a space or carriage return after you enter your first value? `scanf` waits until a carriage return, although it will split the input on whitespace...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are inputting a letter or string for the first input, which would result in "skipping" the second input (since the first scan wouldn't consume the letter and the second scan would fail).

Either scan the suit to a character or string:

```
char *suit;
suit = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
scanf("%s\n", suit);
```

or input two numbers